# Help with stain on white coffee table

Tags: stain, table

I have recently discovered a light brown ring stain on my white coffee table. I have no idea where it came from (I'm still racking my brain for things I've put on the table that would create this shape). It won't come off from normal cleaning with a cloth/cleaning product. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get rid of the stain? [image]

Comment: It's not obvious from the picture what the table top is made of - is it marble/stone?

Comment: textured laminate?

Comment: I see a ring and a pattern like a magazine had moisture on it? I have had some luck with hydrogen peroxide (not the stuff in the grocery store) I get + 25% maybe 33% from a chemical store it will take the color out of just about of anything I have spilled it on oops white spot. I normally use ~ 3% to kill mold it works great. It may clean the laminate but I would check in a non visible area , cleanup with water is easy , use gloves it makes your skin turn white and puffy at full strength if your glove leaks but will go back to normal after rinsing and airing out add acid to water to dilute.